# Delete all cookies in the browser using js?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

how can I delete all cookies in the browser using js?
I found an extension for firefox that uses API cookies, but it does not delete all data:

```
var count = 0;

browser.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
  count = cookies.length;
  document.getElementById("cookie-counter").innerHTML = count;
});

function clearAllCookies() {
  console.log("cookies cleared");
  browser.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
    for (var i in cookies) {
      removeCookie(cookies[i]);
    }
  });
}

function removeCookie(cookie) {
  var url = "http" + (cookie.secure ? "s" : "") + "://" + cookie.domain +
    cookie.path;
  browser.cookies.remove({
    "url": url,
    "name": cookie.name
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var link = document.getElementById('clear-cookies');
  // onClick's logic below:
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearAllCookies();
  });
});
```

But the data remains in the cookie storage in the browser settings. Why does this happen and is it possible to completely clean them using js?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks4Dd.png)

Comment: TBH: Seems suspicious to allow any website to clear *other* website's cookies.  Extensions run as part of the browser, not as part of a webite.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) `browser.cookies.getAll()` returns a promise, it doesn't take a callback function.

Comment: @freedomn-m Where did they say they ran this in a website?

Comment: Simply use browser.browsingData.removeCookies.